# Button's onClick not returning id

Tags: reactjs, onclick

I'm trying to read the `id` of a `<Button />` component when it's clicked:

```
const FlagsDialog = (props) => {
  const {
    classes,
    handleClose,
    showFlagsDialog,
  } = props;

  const selectLang = (evt) => {
    console.log('CLICKED', evt.target.id);
  };

  return (
    <Dialog
      open={showFlagsDialog}
      onClose={handleClose}
      aria-labelledby="alert-dialog-title"
      aria-describedby="alert-dialog-description"
    >
      <Button onClick={selectLang} id="en">English</Button>
      <Button onClick={selectLang} id="es">Spanish</Button>
      <Button onClick={selectLang} id="fr">French</Button>
      <Button onClick={selectLang} id="de">German</Button>
    </Dialog>
  );
};
```

But when run, the click only returns the text `CLICKED`, and no value for the clicked button's `id`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: the issue is with `Button` so you need to share that. If you use `button` it works as expected

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you're trying to do, but that code works.

I'm assiming `Button` and `Dialog` are your custom components (if not, you need to change them to `button` and `dialog`). I changed them to `button` and `dialog` in the code that I used and it works fine.

Here, check it out:

[image: Edit falling-dew-dh1pn]

Answer (score 0):

use a method instead of event for passing id as parameter.

```
 const FlagsDialog = (props) => {
      const {
        classes,
        handleClose,
        showFlagsDialog,
      } = props;

      const selectLang = (id) => {
        console.log(id);
//OR e.target.getAttribute("id")
      };

      return (
        <Dialog
          open={showFlagsDialog}
          onClose={handleClose}
          aria-labelledby="alert-dialog-title"
          aria-describedby="alert-dialog-description"
        >
          <Button onClick={() => this.selectLang(id)} id="en">English</Button>
          <Button onClick={selectLang} id="en">English</Button>
        </Dialog>
      );
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use the fancy-pant ref function:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  btns = [];

  handleClick = index => console.log(this.btns[index].id);

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button
          ref={ref => (this.btns[0] = ref)}
          onClick={() => this.handleClick(0)}
          id="no1"
        >
          First
        </button>
        <button
          ref={ref => (this.btns[1] = ref)}
          onClick={() => this.handleClick(1)}
          id="no2"
        >
          Second
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Edit ref-buttons]

Turns out this ref implementation is simpler than I expected.